# Android Studio subprojects

Tags: android, android-studio

All the examples/samples I've seen concern one app in one project in one package. Can I put two apps into the same project? into the same package? in Android Studio? I am obviously unclear on the concepts. I also don't know if a limitation will be due to the concepts or my choice of tool. I'll give an example. Suppose two apps are extremely closely related and share a lot of code as Adobe Acrobat and Adobe Reader must be. I assume Reader to be simply a subset of Acrobat code, plus a little of its own code. Could their code reside in the same package? project?

Could this be the case: Project & package = com.adobe.pdfapps

Apps = com.adobe.pdfapps.acrobat + com.adobe.pdfapps.reader (+ com.adobe.pdfapps.mobileviewer, + etc.)

So, there would be multiple apps and main activities within the project/package.

If I can organize my related apps in this manner, can I do so with Android Studio? if so, how?

Or is this addressed through build tools such as Gradle? (Yes. I am ready to write my app's viewer.)
Thanks

Comment: I'm confused on what you've got going on in your post. But, if you have common code between projects then you can put that in a library or library project then declare it as a dependency for the projects which need it.

Answer (score 0):

Precisely for this requirement you have libraries. Taking you example into consideration, this is how it should work:

1. The project would be divided into several libraries, with each having its own task (there would be one library for PDF rendering, one for creating annotations, one for editing a PDF, one for converting it to a different format, etc).
2. Now, since Reader and Acrobat have different set of tasks, they import different libraries into their main project, which they add as dependencies in their build.gradle file. For instance, Reader being the lighter one, imports PDF renderer, but not PDF Editing library, while acrobat imports all of them.
3. Dividing it into packages has nothing to do with separation of apps, its just a way to logically separate tasks of your code. To actually separate out tasks to suit your apps, you need to separate them out as libraries, and then import them as dependencies.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer and codeMagic's confirm my suspicion: I think about coding all wrong. I think in terms of applications and objects within those applications. I should be thinking more in terms of code and making applications out of different combinations of that code base. Just a gestalt switch, but it will be very difficult to absorb and become natural. Similar to switching from procedural to object programming.